# How to delete particular rows from DataFrame?

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I want to select only those rows in DataFrame `df` that have the values `d1` or `d2` in the column `device` OR the `id` column is equal to 0.

I executed the following code:

```
df = df.where("id=0 or device in ('d1', 'd2')")
```

However, when I run this code:

```
df.select('device').distinct().rdd.map(lambda r: r[0]).collect()
```

.., I get this result:

```
d1
d2
d3
d4
```

I do not understand why `d3` and `d4` appear?

Comment: Show the initial Dataframe please. Do those have an ID of 0?

Comment: You could do this: `df[(df['id'] == 0) | (df['device'].isin(('d1', 'd2')))]`

Comment: @cricket_007: yes, there are entries that have `id` equal to 0.

Comment: @blacksite: I tested your solution and it leads me to the same issue...

Comment: @Dinosaurius show us your data then... we don't know what you're dealing with.

Comment: Okay, then do you understand your condition? Anything with ID 0 will be selected, regardless of the device label

Comment: @cricket_007: yeah, it was a stupid error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You did

```
df = df.where("id=0 or device in ('d1', 'd2')")
```

Now it will return all the rows with id = 0 or device in df1 , df2 . Now id=0 could have df3/df4 as device

If you want to elimimate df3, df4 you should do

```
df = df.where("id=0 and device in ('d1', 'd2')")
```

Comment: Oh, that was this evident detail:) Thank you so much.